# MPI with thread support and Bcast calls

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mpi, openmpi

I was wondering if in an MPI program where you specify that there is thread support, all the threads make an MPI::Bcast call (making shure that in the call, the sender process only possesses one thread), is this received by all the other threads or just for one thread from each process (the fastest)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common MPI implementations deal with communication among processes. Implementations supporting threads simply allow multiple threads to make some or all MPI calls, rather than just one. Every one of `T` threads in a process calling `MPI_Bcast` means that the process has called `MPI_Bcast` T times, and expects that all of the other ranks on the communicator will do the same.

Comment: Novelocrat, this makes sense. So having all threads from different processes calling a Bcast it is a major disaster. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Novelocrat, I have one more question, imagine that with multiple thread support enabled, there are two threads in the same process, could they use MPI_Send and MPI_Recv to communicate between them, or would it result in a deadlock?

Comment: A process could probably use Isend/Irecv to communicate with itself, but that would be somewhat silly. Remember, all of the threads in your process are still part of the same MPI rank. Also, `MPI_Send` is allowed to block until the matching receive is complete. If it's to itself, and the receive isn't posted, that's a deadlock.

Comment: At a higher level, if you're explicitly running multiple threads in a process, why would you use MPI to communicate between them? You get all the overhead of interprocess communication, and all the pain of threaded programming.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the level of thread support in your implementation of MPI, (please check, threading support in MPI is very sketchy), MPI call is made only once per process.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer given by Novelocrat:

The basic unit of computation in MPI is the "rank."  In most (all?) interesting implementations of MPI, a rank IS a process.  All of the threads within a process share the same Rank ID.

The MPI Standard supports multiple levels of thread parallelism:  MPI_THREAD_SINGLE, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED, and MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE.

Of these, only MPI_THREAD_MULTILE actually has multiple threads making overlapping calls into the MPI library.  The other three cases are an assertion from the application that the Rank can be treated as if it were "single threaded."  For more, see the [MPI Standard entry on MPI_INIT_THREAD](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-20-html/node165.htm).